# Can vim-plug write plugin settings directly to .vimrc?

Tags: vimrc, plugin-system, plugin-vim-plug

I am new in using vim-plug. It works fine installing and updating all the plugins configured in `.vimrc`. But some plugins require some additional settings inside `.vimrc` to work correctly.

Is there a way to make vim-plug do this automatically too (would be a pain after installing 10 or more plugins at once)?

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/117883/discussion-on-question-by-mountain-can-vim-plug-write-plugin-settings-directly-t).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's an interesting question! To my knowledge, there is no option to do so.

I think it's better to let the user chose his own mapping to avoid collisions. This is the reason why some plugins use `<Plug>` for their features (see `:help using-<Plug>`).

I am happy to see that you are keen on plugins (they are really useful), but I suggest you to not install too many of them (in my humble opinion).

Some plugins duplicate features already existing in vim and I think your knowledge about vim is more portable than any plugins.

Answer (score 0):

In theory it could be possible to hack this together using the `do` option to `Plug`.  From the [plug documentation](https://github.com/junegunn/vim-plug/blob/a9bf5bd72212ff7cf9e9e863c365a3464faa2426/doc/plug.txt#L206-L221):

```
                                                                  *plug-options*
                                                                         *:Plug*

 ------------------------+-----------------------------------------------
 Option                  | Description                                   ~
 ------------------------+-----------------------------------------------
  `branch` / `tag` / `commit`  | Branch/tag/commit of the repository to use
  `rtp`                    | Subdirectory that contains Vim plugin
  `dir`                    | Custom directory for the plugin
  `as`                     | Use different name for the plugin
  `do`                     | Post-update hook (string or funcref)
  `on`                     | On-demand loading: Commands or <Plug>-mappings
  `for`                    | On-demand loading: File types
  `frozen`                 | Do not update unless explicitly specified
 ------------------------+-----------------------------------------------
```

However, I'm not sure of the use case for this: you would be writing code to write settings, when you may as well write the settings themselves.  It may help you to know that even if a certain plugin is not installed, you can still set options with `let g:my_plugin_option = "value"` with no ill effect.  Furthermore, many plugins set `g:loaded_plugin_name` which you could use inside a conditional, although you'd have to pay attention to your `&runtimepath` order.